# Python Pandas count result of aggregate function with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, aggregate

I'm struggling to put this into words, but I'm trying to 'count' the amount of times the count of a group of two columns is above 2.

I have a DataFrame with 2 "keys":

```
#The 'data' isn't important here, but it exists
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : [1,5,1,2,6,3,3,3,4,4,4,7],
                   'key2' : [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],
                   'data' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I'm grouping by key1 & key2 and counting the amount of times they are the same:

```py
new_df = df.groupby(['key1','key2']).agg(['count'])
print(new_df)
```

Which outputs:

```
           data
          count
key1 key2      
1    1        2
2    2        1
3    3        3
4    4        3
5    1        1
6    2        1
7    4        1
```

I need to be able to count how many times the key1 & key2 group occurred more than 2 times. ie. **I want to count the amount of times 'data count' is above 2** (twice in this example)

something like:

```
len(new_df.loc[new_df['data'] > 2])
```

But this won't work and gives me the error:

```
NotImplementedError: Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented
```

I'm looking for an as efficient solution as possible, as my original df can quite large.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `key1 and key` then use the aggregate function [`Groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then use [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) to create a boolean mask where the `True` values occur where the size of group is greater than 2, then use [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) to count the total such groups:

```
mask = df.groupby(['key1','key2']).size().gt(2)
count = mask.sum()
```

Result:

```
# print(mask)
key1  key2
1     1       False
2     2       False
3     3        True
4     4        True
5     1       False
6     2       False
7     4       False
dtype: bool

# print(count)
2
```